# android File.mkdirs() always return false

Tags: android

I want make directory and file in device.

but when File.mkdirs() always return false...
I don't know why!

I even have added permission in manifest like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="pkg.pkg.pkg">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
....
```

and this is my code :

```
File directory = null;
File file = null;
String dir = "";
String folderName = "test";

String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if(sdcard.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
} else {
    dir = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
}

directory = new File(dir, folderName);

if(!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs(); // return false here.
}

if(directory.isDirectory()){

    file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
    if(file.exists()){
        String tempFileName = et_export.getText().toString();

        // Check duplicate file name
        for(int i=1;;i++){
            fileName = tempFileName + " (" + i + ").png";
            file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
            if(!file.exists()) break;
        } // for

    } // if(file.exists())

} // if(directory.isDirectory())
```

What's the problem...?

Comment: you can put some log here.

Comment: `directory.mkdirs();` Better: `if ( !directory.mkdirs()) return;` you could also display a toast yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

you need to manually code the permission granting part (besides defining it in the manifest).

the following is a snippet from  developer.android.com

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```